# How to update an app in Google play console if you lost a key?

Tags: android, google-play, adb, google-play-console

Here's the problem: I transfered an ownership of my app to other dude, and now he's facing a problem with updating it (I lost the key that I used to sign AAB-file). We had already wrote an email to Play Console support. Here's the response:

Good news - I was able to register a new upload key for your app, 'app name'. The new key will be usable from: 'time'.Make sure to update your keystores in the following locations:Local machine Locked on-site server (varying ACLs) Cloud machine (varying ACLs) Dedicated secrets management services (git) repos Thanks for your patience during this process, and please let me know if you have any other questions.

After that he tried to update an app, but faced such a mistake:

app bundle is signed with the wrong key. Choose the correct key and try again. App bundle should be signed with the sertificate with such digital fingerprint: SHA1: ............................. But the AAB that you've uploded is signed with sertificate with such a fingerprint: SHA1: ......(different fingerprint).

Whad do I do wrong and what should I do to finally update this app?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's unrelated to programming. This should be addressed to technical support.

Comment: Did they sign the aab with the same keystore they generated the new upload certificate from?